# Python OpenCV2 cv2.cv_fourcc not working with VideoWriter

Tags: python, opencv

As the title states, when I run the cv2.videowriter function I get 'module' object has no attribute CV_FOURCC.

Code:

```
# Creates a video file from webcam stream
import cv2

Create test window
cv2.namedWindow("cam_out", cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

# Create vid cap object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1)


# Create video writer object
vidwrite = cv2.VideoWriter(['testvideo', cv2.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 25, 
               (640,480),True])
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @KyleMaxwell The questions is _”How do I fix the error ‘'module' object has no attribute CV_FOURCC’ when I run the cv2.videowriter function?”_

Answer (score 35):

Kind of late to the party, but if anyone needs it for newer versions of opencv2, then the command is:

```
cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(c1, c2, c3, c4)
```

Comment: @GM - you need to check which API version you have, all the possibilities are present among the various answers...

Answer (score 17):

Change `cv2.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')` to `cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')`.

Comment: or even cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'MJPG')

Comment: cv module is gone in latest version

Comment: These days you would use `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')`

Answer (score 12):

For OpenCV 3 do this:

`cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')`

credit @SiffgyF

Answer (score 8):

With OpenCV 3:

```
# Create video writer object
vidwrite = cv2.VideoWriter('testvideo.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 25, 
           (640,480),True)
```

you can find the sample at "opencv_install_dir\sources\doc\py_tutorials\py_gui\py_video_display\py_video_display.markdown"

ps: I can't find any description with 'cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(...)' in official documentation.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html - Saving a Video - Section

Answer (score 2):

From experience, if on OSX, this is what worked for me when writing out to mp4 files:

`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to write to Mp4 file just use this codec it's for 2020 opencv4.2 and plus

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('outeringe.mp4', fourcc, 20, (640, 480))
```

use x264 instead of MP4V

Answer (score 1):

For those encountering a `"VideoWriter_fourcc" is not a known member of module "cv2"` error from pylance, it seems the method is not defined in the type stubs definition file (.pyi); There's discussion related to such on the opencv GH repo [#24818](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/24818). TLDR; Fix is targeted for v4.10.

Many examples shows something like:

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
vwriter = cv2.VideoWriter("outvideo.mp4", fourcc, 20, (640, 480))
```

As mentioned, pylance will likely complain with the above,
An alternative that will work without falsly trigging pylance is:

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*"mp4v")
vwriter = cv2.VideoWriter("outvideo.mp4", fourcc, 20, (640, 480))
```

in the source code fourcc is marked as a static method of videowriter class, and needs to be called on an instance of the class.

Note this is for v.4.9 and I don't know which version this was introduced

Answer (score 0):

I've the same error (on macos ) in opencv-python        4.2.0.32
upgrading to opencv-python-4.4.0.46 solve it , without any need for code changes

Answer (score -1):

I use this code:

```
fourcc = cv2.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
```

Comment: Please describe why this answers the question and how the code you supplied should be used.

Comment: Not working. Gives: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_FOURCC'