# How to improve OpenCV and python VideoWriter resolution?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a script which uses `OpenCV` and `python` and creates a video ( `avi` format ) from a set of **`png`** images.

**The resolution of these images is good.**

The problem is that the resolution of the resulting video is very low.

How can I improve the resolution?

Is the low resolution related to the images format?

**CODE:**

```
writer  = cv2.VideoWriter( "C:\Users\.../demo3_4.avi", -1, 1, ( width, height ) )
nFrames = 24

for i in range( 1, nFrames ):
    img   = cv2.imread( os.path.join( str( inf ), "colorraster%d.jpg"%i ) )
    writer.write( img )

cv2.destroyAllWindows()  
writer.release()
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of your images? Did you read the [class description in the manual](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter)? What did you set the resolution of your VideoWriter (5th number at instantiation)? Could you show some code?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Otherwise it wont be easy to help you...

Comment: ljetibo, the images have 73*59 pixels.

Comment: Does cv2.VideoWriter have some options where you can set the desired resolution?

Comment: Try changing fourcc parameter of cv2.VideoWriter, instead of providing the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html), `cv2.VideoWriter` has `fourcc` parameter which specifies the [codec](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php), used to compress the frames. You are now specifying '-1' which means some default codec. I would suggest experimenting with different codecs from that list and see what gives the best result.

Update: To translate the codec into an int, the docs recommend this: `CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1')` if you wanted to try codec PIM1.

Comment: I am searching in fourcc documentation but I don't understand the codes used. I have '-1', default code, but I didn't see this code in list http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php.

Comment: It is not there because it's just "the default".

Comment: I try what you said but python doesn't recognize CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1') in my code.

Comment: well, for python it should be in slighlty different form I guess. Just found it mentioned in another answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584608/python-opencv2-cv2-cv-fourcc-not-working-with-videowriterb) : cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('P','I','M','1')

Comment: Ok. I get it!! But know I try several codecs but the video never works, juts works with '-1'.  What is the best codec for windows media player?

Comment: Yes. I see in some comments to try with lower letters like this, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('p','i','m','1') and I try also but without success.

Comment: Could you check with some other tool whether you produced correct divx (assuming you used divx codec)?

Comment: Another idea, may be the codecs on your machine have to be updated / additional codecs have to be installed.

Comment: No success.... The problem is that I am developing a script that may be used by other users and this could be dependent of the other computers. Is there an easy way to handle a set of images and create a simple video using python?

Comment: Without success... I didn't find any codec that works in my script, only '-1' works and with a very very low resolution.

Comment: So, I am trying to update/install the codec DIVX in my pc. Can you tell where I can download DIVX for windows 8?

Comment: I don't use Windows, but googling gives this link: http://www.windows8codecs.com/ perhaps useful?

Comment: I try but without results yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

### How to improve resolution?

Generate the output stream with a reasonable pixel-size **`frameSize`** and do not devastate the information quality ( you have stated above to have in the inputs ( in static pixmaps ) ) with a "cummulative product" of low **`FPS`** frames-per-second rate and too-lossy CODEC ( **`CV_FOURCC`** ).

### SYNTAX:

```
>>> print cv2.VideoWriter.__doc__
VideoWriter( [ filename,
               fourcc,           # <--------- ref. below
               fps,              #            1 fps
               frameSize[,       #            73 * 59 px
               isColor  ]
               ]
              ) -> <VideoWriter object>

>>> print cv2.cv.FOURCC.__doc__
CV_FOURCC(c1, c2, c3, c4) -> int

>>> cv2.cv.FOURCC( *"XVID" )    1145656920
>>> cv2.cv.FOURCC( *"MJPG" )    1196444237
>>> cv2.cv.FOURCC( *"X264" )     875967064
>>> cv2.cv.FOURCC( *"DIB " )     541215044
>>> cv2.cv.FOURCC( *"WMV1" )     827739479
>>> cv2.cv.FOURCC( *"WMV2" )     844516695
```

### Further readings:

> **FourCC** is a 4-byte code used to specify the video codec.
>                                                                               The list of available codes can be found in fourcc.org.
>                                                                               It is platform dependent.
>                                                                               Following codecs work fine:
>                                                                                   In Fedora:  **`DIVX`**, **`XVID`**, **`MJPG`**, **`X264`**, **`WMV1`**, **`WMV2`**. ( `XVID` is more preferable. `MJPG` results in high size video. `X264` gives very small size video )
>                                                                                   In Windows: **`DIVX`** ( more to be tested and added )
>
> **FourCC** code is passed as **`cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')`**
>                                                                                                     or **`cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG)`** for `MJPG`.

```
"""                                                                 # >>> http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html#gsc.tab=0
fourcc  = cv2.cv.FOURCC(  *"DIB " )
video   = cv2.VideoWriter( 'ATC_LKPR_output.avi', fourcc, 30, size ) # fps = 30, size = ( 1024, 512 )
```

Comment: I also try this approach but gives me an error that cv2.cv doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

open cv screen recorded video is low quality when you play these files using unsupported codec player .
i was getting low quality video while i was playing on windows media player and after lot of analysis when i tried on VLC media Player .boom video quality is superb.
so just change media player to try if video is still poor quality.