# how to record screen in high quality

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, winapi

i am creating a screen recorder for desktop in python. and i have already completed the coding part but when i record the screen why it is not recording in high defination. 
problem.........
1> i want to record the screen in high quality what should i do.
2> i am also trying to capute my cursor with the help on cv2.circle() but i want to create the circle with less opacity or more transparent

my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import datetime
import win32api

date=datetime.datetime.now()

SCREEN_SIZE = (960,540) #std res 1366, 768
framerate=12
# define the codec
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
filename='E:/project/videos/rec_%s%s%s%s%s%s.avi' %(date.year,date.month,date.day,date.hour,date.minute,date.second)

out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc,framerate, SCREEN_SIZE)

while True:

    img = pyautogui.screenshot()

    frame = np.array(img)

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    _xs,_ys = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    image=cv2.circle(frame,(_xs,_ys),20,(0,255,255,0.3),-1)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(960,540)) #resize window

    out.write(frame)

    cv2.imshow('screenshot', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `cv2.videowriter`, make sure that the framesize is equal to the size of the screen so that the image is not distorted.

In addition, if you need to record the screen, you should make sure that the opencv window does not affect the beauty of the entire desktop.

In my code, I have added a translucent circle. You can change the transparency of the circle as needed.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
import datetime
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
import win32api

flag=False 

def transparent_circle(img,center,radius,color,thickness):
    center = tuple(map(int,center))
    rgb = [255*c for c in color[:3]] # convert to 0-255 scale for OpenCV
    alpha = color[-1]
    radius = int(radius)
    if thickness > 0:
        pad = radius + 2 + thickness
    else:
        pad = radius + 3
    roi = slice(center[1]-pad,center[1]+pad),slice(center[0]-pad,center[0]+pad)

    try:
        overlay = img[roi].copy()
        cv2.circle(img,center,radius,rgb, thickness=thickness, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
        opacity = alpha
        cv2.addWeighted(src1=img[roi], alpha=opacity, src2=overlay, beta=1. - opacity, gamma=0, dst=img[roi])
    except:
        logger.debug("transparent_circle would have been partially outside of img. Did not draw it.") 

def video_record():
    date=datetime.datetime.now()
    filename='path/rec_%s%s%s%s%s%s.avi' %(date.year,date.month,date.day,date.hour,date.minute,date.second)
    p = ImageGrab.grab()  
    a, b = p.size 
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') 
    video = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 20, (a, b)) 
    while True:
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
        imm=cv2.cvtColor(np.array(im), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        _xs,_ys = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        transparent_circle(imm,(_xs,_ys),20,(0,255,255,0.5), -1)
#       cv2.circle(imm,(_xs,_ys),20,(0,255,255,0.3),-1)                 
        video.write(imm)
        if flag:
            print("Record Over")
            break
    video.release()
def on_press(key):
    global flag
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        flag=True
        print("stop monitor")
        return False  

if __name__=='__main__':
    th=threading.Thread(target=video_record)
    th.start()
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

[image]

When you run the code, start recording. When you press the `ESC` key, stop recording and save the file.

Note: You may need to add some libraries, otherwise there will be an error that the module cannot be found

Comment: it was nice but can i display the current recording in a label of a pyqt5 window or in tkinter in gui with start and stop recording buttons. can you show me how can i do that part.

Comment: @arvind8 If you have a new question, welcome to post a new question to find the answer, please be sure to provide enough clear details:)

Comment: the output of your code is not in high defination how can i get the output in high defination by changing the codec to H.264 or any other or by changing the file extention.

Comment: @arvind8 does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353246/how-to-improve-opencv-and-python-videowriter-resolution) help?