# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cv'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('1.MP4')
fourcc = cv2.FOURCC(*'XVID')
out  = cv2.videoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,480))

while (1):
  #Capture frame-by-frame
  #ret = cap.set(3,960),cap.set(4,720)
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:
      frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
      out.write(frame)

      cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

      if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
          break
  else:
      break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As is shown above ,this is a demo in opencv document.while it can work in my PC.
Traceback like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\opencv\Pic\test.py", line 34, in <module>
    fourcc = cv2.cv.FOURCC(*'XVID')
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cv'
```

And i also see some solution such as change cv2.cv to cv2 ,while the traceback below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\opencv\Pic\test.py", line 34, in <module>
    fourcc = cv2.FOURCC(*'XVID')
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'FOURCC'
```

i am very thanks any warm heart solution for my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python OpenCV2 cv2.cv\_fourcc not working with VideoWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584608/python-opencv2-cv2-cv-fourcc-not-working-with-videowriter)

Answer (score 3):

The link @Spence wetjen post is for old OpenCV, won't work in OpenCV 3.x.

Here is my code:

---

Env: Python3 + OpenCV 3.3

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cv2

## opening videocapture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

## some videowriter props
sz = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
        int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

fps = 20
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', 'e', 'g')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mpeg')

## open and set props
vout = cv2.VideoWriter()
vout.open('output.mp4',fourcc,fps,sz,True)

cnt = 0
while cnt<20:
    cnt += 1
    print(cnt)
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.putText(frame, str(cnt), (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    vout.write(frame)

vout.release()
cap.release()
```

---

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Import the contrib library as well.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

or

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```